# Difference between a primitive construct and a primitive data type?

Tags: readability, orthogonal

I'm reading a textbook evaluating a programming language implementation and I'm easily confused by terminology that I don't understand, but know how to use when writing a program. This is in regards to orthogonality of an implementation.

> *"Orthogonality in a programming language means that a relatively small set of primitive constructs can be combined in a relatively small number of ways to build the control and data structures of the language"*

Comment: Sorry for just posting links, but perhaps this explains it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set#Orthogonality_in_practice or the addition-example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_(programming)